# Does the colimit topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ make it a TVS?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, vector-spaces

Consider $V = \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, endowed with the colimit topology from viewing $V$ as the colimit of the sequence $\mathbb{R}^0 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^1 \hookrightarrow \cdots$ of inclusions of topological spaces.

We note that as just a vector space, $V$ can be viewed as the direct sum $\mathbb{R}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$.

I was wondering what would be the best way to determine whether vector addition and scalar multiplication on $V$ are continuous for the colimit topology?

---

Also, according to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_topological_vector_spaces) (see the last bullet point in the 2nd section), the category of topological vector spaces is (co)complete, hence there should exist a $V'$ which is a TVS and is the colimit, in the category of TVSs, of $\mathbb{R}^0 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^1 \hookrightarrow \cdots$.

I would imagine the forgetful functor from TVSs to vector spaces has a left adjoint (given by equipping the discrete topology), hence is colimit-preserving, so $V'$ should be the "same" vector space as $V$.

However, it doesn't seem like the same can be said about the forgetful functor from TVSs to topological spaces; so, here $V'$ could have a different topology from (the colimit topology on) $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing the [space of all finite sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#Space_of_all_finite_sequences), which is the topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ wherein $\{s_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\to s_{\infty}$ iff

1. (Discrete tightness) There exists $J$ such that, for all $j\geq J$, there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $(s_n)_j=0$; and
2. (Pointwise convergence) For all $j$, $\{(s_n)_j\}_n\to(s_{\infty})_j$.

If so, then to show that the vector space operations are continuous is a straightforward exercise from the definitions.

Comment: Thank you Jacob, this was helpful!